# Why cannot calculate the gapped Higgs mode in superfluid?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, higgs, superfluidity

According to Ch. 4.2 in *Quantum Field Theory in Condensed Matter Physics* by N.Nagaosa, when we deal with superfluid problem, bosonic field can be decompose into amplitude and phase:
$$\begin{array}{l}\psi(r, \tau)=[\rho(r, \tau)]^{1 / 2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta(r, \tau)} \\ \bar{\psi}(r, \tau)=[\rho(r, \tau)]^{1 / 2} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \theta(\boldsymbol{r}, \tau)}\end{array}$$
and weak-coupling model can be simplified as:
$$S \cong \int_{0}^{\beta} \mathrm{d} \tau \int \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{r}\left\{\mathrm{i} \delta \rho \partial_{\tau} \theta+\frac{\psi_{0}^{2}}{2 m}(\nabla \theta)^{2}+\frac{1}{2} g(\delta \rho)^{2}-\delta \mu \delta \rho\right\}$$
And the Green function matrix is:
$$\left\langle\left[\begin{array}{c}\delta \rho(k) \\ \theta(k)\end{array}\right]^{t}\left[\begin{array}{c}\delta \rho(-k) \\ \theta(-k)\end{array}\right]\right\rangle=\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\frac{g \psi_{0}^{2}}{4 m}|k|^{2}+\frac{\omega_{n}^{2}}{4}}\left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac{\psi_{0}^{2}}{2 m}|k|^{2} & -\frac{\omega_{n}}{2} \\ \frac{\omega_{n}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} g\end{array}\right]$$
we can find that $\langle \delta\rho(k)\delta \rho(-k)\rangle  $ has singularity even as $\omega_n \rightarrow0$, although the wight $k2$ is also $\rightarrow0$. In the other words, it seems this "Higgs mode" is "gapless"(not exactly since zero-energy has no weight). Namely, the spectral function for $\delta \rho$ is following:
[image]
I am confused that this "Higgs mode" is not gapped, i.e. has no singularity as $\omega<\Delta$. What's the reason of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are sound modes. As the fluid moves backward and forward (motion of the order parameter $\langle \psi\rangle$  along the potential minumum $\theta$ direction) the density also changes (radial mtion in $\rho$ direction -- the "Higgs" mode) so that moving forward corresponds to higher density and moving backwards to lower. Thus, in a superfluid, and unlike the relativistic Higgs where the motion along the minimum is a gapless Goldstone mode that is uncoupled from the  massive radial Higgs mode, there are  no separate Goldstone and Higgs modes. Instead, there is just one ungapped sound  mode.